# jquery plugin that switches divs with text

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

I'm looking for jquery plugin that can switch content with buttons.

e.g.

In the page it would look like this:
**[Prev] some text within a div  [Next]**

By pressing a button (next or prev) the div changes with the content to next div in the page that probably is hidden before pressing the buttom... something like that.

I hope you got my idea!

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is easily achievable without a plugin.  Store an array of text so you have a number to reference each and then start with first element, when they click next load in the currentNumber+1 text from the array.

Comment: I would do that if I had JS skills... :(

Comment: I think this can be done pretty easily or you can develop a simple plugin too... post the code which you have done so far and we can help

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any, that is why I'm looking for a plugin.

Comment: Could you at least show the html mark-up you're working with?

Comment: I don't have any yet. I'm just looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a plugin, you can see a simple working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gfosco/fG9N9/

Comment: What is with that "framework onLoad" ? I copied it but it doesn't work.. should I add something?

Comment: the code should be in a `$(document).ready(function() {   <the-js-code-here>   });`  block.

Comment: Just one more thing... why when it dispalys content, it removes/doesn't show any formating, tags - <b><span> etc?

Comment: @arturs ah, replace the `.text()` references with `.html()`